# WebSockets for Android AND iOS Apps

Tags: android, ios, websocket

Is there a project that provides libraries for communication over WebSocket for both Android and iOS? I know jWebSocket, but it is pretty much dead, and does not provide a lib for iOS. I know Autobahn, but it too supports only Android. I also know SocketRocket, but that is only for iOS. Is there something that supports both, or two solutions that are 100% compatible with WebSocket?

Thanks!

Comment: there is no supporting both iOS (objC) and Android (java)

Comment: is there something that is compatible at least?

Comment: there is no compatibility between ios and android whatsoever. That's 2 different languages

Comment: I don't mean compatibility of iOS and Android, I mean the compatibility of the WebSocket implementations e.g. if I implement a messaging service with one framework on android, will it be able to communicate with a service developed with different framework on iOS?

Comment: if you develop it so, yes. if you use standard implementation of the mechanisms you use, there is no reason for it no to be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iOS uses ObjectiveC and Android Java, so there can't be a library that provides building the same unmodified user source code for both platforms for the platform's native language. You could have that (in principle) using C. And of course JavaScript.

Apart from that regarding the wire protocol AutobahnAndroid and SocketRocket should be absolutely compatible, since both use the AutobahnTestsuite to test protocol compliance.

Above is for pure WebSocket. If you want to use higher level features of i.e. Autobahn like the Publish & Subscribe and RPC messaging patterns provided by [WAMP](http://wamp.ws), we plan to have a iOS version of Autobahn that adds those .. *on top of* SocketRocket. No need to reinvent a mature, robust WebSocket implementation on iOS.

Disclaimer: I am creator of Autobahn/WAMP.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the difference :) what I want to do is develop 2 Apps, one for Android and one for iOS and let them both communicate via WebSockets. Now, I don't want to reinvent the wheel and write everything on my own - that's why I'm looking for some framework that provides libs for both iOS and Android. If I understood you correctly, Autobahn+SocketRocket+your future addon would provide this (including RPCs and the pub/sub mechanism)?

Comment: with "provide this" I mean that they are compatible

Comment: On the pure WebSocket level, AutobahnAndroid and SocketRocket should be 100% compatible (wire protocol) as today. For WAMP (= PubSub + RPC), yeah, we plan to have AutobahnIOS, and then both (and also AutobahnJS and AutobahnPython, which already exist today) should be working together. I cannot give you a timeline though ..

Comment: Update: there is a new project implementing WAMP on top of SocketRocket for iOS: https://github.com/mogui/MDWamp

Comment: Hello @oberstet have you come out with iOS version of Autobahn yet ?

Comment: @UndercoverDeveloper no, and we don't have plans to do so, since there is MDWamp - which is actively maintained http://wamp.ws/implementations/